Are questions about cognitive aspect of spirituality on-topic?
If there is no god from where does spiritual feeling came from
This question asks (emphasis mine):

I can't differentiate if spiritual feeling is because of my childhood memory or is genetically embedded in me.

I think the field cognitive science of religion can answer this, or at least has some frameworks to attempt to answer this. From the link:

Scholars in this field seek to explain how human minds acquire, generate, and transmit religious thoughts, practices, and schemas by means of ordinary cognitive capacities. 

So I think the question is on-topic. What do you think?

Relate:
• How to measure the correlation between "spirituality" and the susceptibility to false memories?
• If restructuring question's body can set a new expectation on the readers, and thus making it clearer to be on-topic, should this be done?

Questions about the cognitive origins of spirituality are on-topic.  Questions about the behavior of an individual are off-topic.
The quoted part, as well as the rest of the question, are clearly about the poster (emphasis mine):

I can't differentiate if spiritual feeling is because of my childhood
  memory or is genetically embedded in me.

I can see how this question could be rephrased to apply more generally.  Feel free to edit it accordingly if you would like to see it reopened.

I think the note part of the OP negates any assumption that the question is about their personal experience

@Ooker In addition, we require some initial research, which the linked question is also lacking.

@StevenJeuris yes, but it should be closed as lacking of research, not as off-topic. We do have that notice, iirc

@Ooker In the end, I closed as duplicate, which should always have preference if you ask me. In that same answer I also argue that 'self-help' is overused and 'not framed in' should be preferred. The 'self-help' close reason almost always results in users saying 'but I don't seek help', or 'I am already seeking help', disregarding the "single individual" part. Maybe we should rewrite the close reasons and include 'single individual' in 'not framed in' and focus 'self-help' solely on help seekers.

I don't think it's typically worth bickering over why a question is closed, often the reasons overlap a bit. The exception might be closing as duplicate which I agree is always preferable when appropriate.
